# Generating Doxygen for C# projects with generic collections

Tags: c#, list, generics, doxygen

I am using Doxygen and GraphViz Dot to generate some collaboration diagrams for a C# project.  The problem is generic collections (like `List<>`) are not recognised by Doxygen.  Does anyone have a solution to this?

I found [this comment](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.text.doxygen.general/5830) that doesn't seem very hopeful, but was wondering if there are any work-arounds.

Comment: Using Doxygen 1.8.2 (latest release as of right now), generics [look fine to me](http://i.imgur.com/mN6hc.png).  Are you using an older version or is there something else that isn't working right?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk, Unfortunately support for generics is incomplete; this is evident when you attempt to generate diagrams of a simple class that has e.g. `List<T> children` where `T` is a custom type within same project, you will not see `children` displayed in the diagram. This occurs even though that same child _is_ listed amongst class members. This using v1.8.2.

Comment: @doxygen Perhaps you can comment on this.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Doxygen's changelog](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/changelog.html#log_1_8_1_1), generics in C# were not being indexed prior to version 1.8.1.1 (released October 6).  I don't see a corresponding bug for it, though looking at previous releases they've been supported for some time now.

As my comment above states, I don't see any issues using the current release (1.8.2).  If that's the version you're using, please specifically mention what isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

there are Issues with Generics and Some thirdPartyControls. I had same Problem. If List<> not supoorted, you can Convert List to Corresponding Array of Objects. Array will support in any Controls and Products.

Just see the example.

Need To convert DataTreeNodeCollection (List) SubNodes into DataTreeNode[]

```
 DataTreeNode[] subNodesArray = new DataTreeNode[SubNodes.size()];

 foreach (DataTreeNode node in SubNodes)
                {
                    subNodesArray[count] = node;
                    count++;
                }
```

Here I converted List to Array.

Comment: hi bradmarxmoosepi, Please let me know, if you have any doubts.

Comment: Or you could use _SubNodes.ToArray()_

Comment: Hi Christoffer, List<> is .Net 2.0 feature. So that's why Used this code. that also one way.

Comment: @Akshay Suggesting not using generics at all just to get around an apparent doxygen limitation is not a good answer.